# Child-Parent Membership structure

Tags: civimember, caldera-forms, wordpress.com

I'm trying to implement a system where a parent can register multiple children. The parent would need to pay for each child's membership. However, if a parent signed up and registered no children, they would not be signed up for a membership. Then, a Wordpress account would be created for every registered person.

So far, I have created a Caldera form where a parent can register multiple children and a relationship is created. However, I was unable to figure out how to create Wordpress accounts through Caldera and how to create memberships for every child, if a child is added.

Thank you in advance for any ideas on how to advance. Worse comes to worse, I can just program it up using the hooks.